# Issues with history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement history.pushState while using .load() function to load content without redirecting the page, the .load() functionality works fine, and the history.pushState works on the first implementation. But when I then click another link it appends to the url...

Here's what I mean:

Main URL: https://materialwebdesign.ltd
Click link and URL becomes: https://materialwebdesign.ltd/inc/material-design
Click another link and URL becomes: https://materialwebdesign.ltd/inc/inc/bootstrap

Why is this happening? Heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#main_content').load('inc/main-content.html', function() {
        $(this).animate({ height: '100%', width: '100%' }, 2000, 'linear');
    });

    $('.dynamic').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var page = $(this).attr('href');

        var title = page.title;

        $('#main_content').html('<div class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-upgraded is-active"></div>');

        if (typeof (history.pushState) != 'undefined') {

            var obj = {Title: title, Url: page}

            $('#main_content').load(page + '.html', function() {
                $(this).animate({ height: '100%', width: '100%' }, 2000, 'linear')
            });

            if(page != window.location){
              history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
            }

            return false; // don't follow the link

        };

    });
});
```

As well as the problem mentioned above, the animation just doesn't animate, if you could help with that too I would appreciate it very much

Comment: I don't see where you use `pushState`. Only `replaceState` everywhere.

Comment: Apologies, while trying various methods I have used bot pushState and replaceState (both have the same problem!) I will edit to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.Url` is a relative URL, so it's interpreted relative to the current URL of the page. Since it contains a subdirectory, every time you do this you add another level of subdirectory to the current page's URL.

Instead of `$(this).attr('href')`, which returns the relative URL in the attribute, use `this.href` -- this will return the `href` property, which is an absolte URL after canonicalization.

Comment: Hey, as in replace `var page = $(this).attr('href');` with `var page = this.href;` (are they not basically the same thing?) ? I just did that and the problem still persists! you could go to my site and check out the problem..

Comment: ...but I am currently developing the site so things may change second by second